# Use nestjs-i18n in a monorepo

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-i18n

I want to use nestjs-i18n in an monorepo project and share i18n assets between apps.
I tried with this configuration but the i18n assets are not copied to the dist directory:

```
    "common": {
          "type": "library",
          "root": "libs/common",
          "entryFile": "index",
          "sourceRoot": "libs/common/src",
          "compilerOptions": {
            "tsConfigPath": "libs/common/tsconfig.lib.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "include": "i18n/**/*"
              }
            ],
            "webpack": true      
 }
```

Any ideas or suggestion? Thanks in advance!